# How to make a copy of torrent to FTP location after download completion

Tags: scripts, bittorrent, transmission

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and using Transmission BitTorrent client for downloading files. All I want is a script which will run after the download has completed and this script will make a exact copy of the files which has been downloaded to a remote FTP location which has an authentication. I do not want to move the files I just want another copy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script as below with appropriate values for LOGFILE, HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DESTINATIONPATH variables in the below shell script. Do not forget to grant execution permission to below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE= #For e.g:- /home/kashif/Desktop/CopyTorrentToFTP.log
HOST= #For e.g:- 192.168.0.1
USERNAME= #For e.g:- admin
PASSWORD= #For e.g:- abcd12345
DESTINATIONPATH= #For e.g:- Movies

SOURCEPATH=$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME
cd "$SOURCEPATH"
echo "Started Copying $SOURCEPATH" >> $LOGFILE
ftp -n $HOST << copy_script
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
prompt
cd "$DESTINATIONPATH"
rmdir "$TR_TORRENT_NAME"
mkdir "$TR_TORRENT_NAME"
cd "$TR_TORRENT_NAME"
mput *
bye
copy_script
echo "Finished Copying $SOURCEPATH" >> $LOGFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Transmission BitTorrent client's option of running a script of your choice after completion of the download.
Here is one approach:

- Create a script to take the name of the latest file/directory in a folder as  its argument
- Next, add the command to copy this latest file/directory to your FTP server. You can take help from this: [FTP file transfer automated bash script](https://www.linux.com/blog/ftp-file-transfer-automated-bash-script)
- Ask Transmission client to run this script every time a download is completed using its built-in option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i get the download which was finished?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132344/61278